# How do I use a database that I have in my backup on Cubicweb?

Tags: python, postgresql, semantic-web

I have my backup in the following path:

/etc/cubicweb.d/myblog/backup

And I want to work with it in local,

How can I use it when creating my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **CubicWeb** you should use the `db-restore` command :

```
cubicweb-ctl db-restore instance myinstance-2010-07-13_10-22-40.tar.gz
```

at your instance backup folder, usually:

```
etc/cubicweb.d/myinstance/backup
```

You will then have your database restored. Here you have more [documentation](https://docs.cubicweb.org/admin/cubicweb-ctl.html#commands-to-maintain-instances).